# CSV file data in structure data for hashing with C

Tags: c, csv, data-structures, hash

I need to read some data from a CSV file and create a data structure, so that I create a hashtable. I have tried a lot and lost a lot of hours but without a result. Please check my code and help me find where the mistake is ...

Here are the file data, output and code.

(I wrote the code alone, with help from C programming language of Deitel and Deitel book.)

## Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct clientData
{
   int acctNum; 

   char breaker[50]; 
   char datetime[60];
   double current;
 };

int main()
{ 
  FILE *cfPtr;

  struct clientData client = {0,"","",0.0 };
  if ( ( cfPtr = fopen("data1.csv","rb") ) == NULL)
  {
    printf("File could not be opened.\n");
  }   
  else
  {
    printf("%-6s%-16s%-11s%10s\n","Acct","Last Name","First Name","Balance");
    
    while ( !feof( cfPtr) )
    {
        fread( &client , sizeof ( struct clientData ), 1 , cfPtr );

        if ( client.acctNum !=0 )
        {
            printf ("%-6d%-16s%-11s%10.2f\n",
                    client.acctNum,client.breaker,client.datetime,client.current );
        }
    }
    fclose ( cfPtr );
  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

## CSV Input file

> acct,breaker,S_TimeStamp,MeasurementValue
> 1,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/20158:30,37.6
> 2,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/20159:00,34.2
> 3,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/20159:30,37.2
> 4,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/201510:00,40.6
> 5,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/201510:30,41.8
> 6,Eth1iotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/201511:00,45.8

## Output

> Acct  Last Name       First Name    Balance
> 1952670561,breaker,S_TimeStamp,MeasurementValue
> 1,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/20158:30,37.6
> 2,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreak@talantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/20158:30,37.6
> 2,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreak@178724158464812467496986462827554460798109233540662154481413250685702096704425934569739618465990294960631478737616585889239313529311067888348744695823558167564353119398296863451093505908419875899425197001801728.00 11116509172Q2Current,1/12/20159:00,34.2
> 3,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/20159:30,37.2
> 4,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2C@VBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/20159:30,37.2
> 4,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2C@5155825882657381.00
> 1701999221nt,1/12/201510:00,40.6
> 5,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/201510:30,41.8
> 6,Eth1iotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Curren@rBB2Q2Current,1/12/201510:30,41.8
> 6,Eth1iotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Curren@62020397019943253271215041932658580009235443368333447944639125867547040589859590642175830919754237423637956114804980964218473105282339526865630710982971497957257635386734871861549462238776468516448931338295812955819267325952.00 79175179612/201511:00,45.8
> 40.6 5,EthiotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Current,1/12/201510:30,41.8 6,Eth1iotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Curren@rBB2Q2Current,1/12/201510:30,41.8
> 6,Eth1iotideAtalantiMVBreakerBB2Q2Curren@62020397019943253271215041932658580009235443368333447944639125867547040589859590642175830919754237423637956114804980964218473105282339526865630710982971497957257635386734871861549462238776468516448931338295812955819267325952.00

Comment: The CSV is `char`s s only. You cannot read anything else from it directly using `fread()`. You need to either parse the text (`char`s) read and convert the result to the specific variables like `int`s and `double`s or use `fscanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct clientData{
    int acctNum; 
    char breaker[50]; 
    char datetime[60];
    double current;
};

int main(void){
    FILE *cfPtr;
    struct clientData client = {0,"","",0.0 };

    if((cfPtr = fopen("data1.csv","r")) == NULL){
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    } else {
        char line[96];
        printf("%-6s%-40s%-20s%10s\n", "Acct", "Breaker", "TimeStamp", "MeasurementValue");

        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, cfPtr)){
            int state = sscanf(line, "%d,%49[^,],%59[^,],%lf", &client.acctNum, client.breaker, client.datetime, &client.current);
            if(state == 4 ) {
                printf("%-6d%-40s%-20s%10.2f\n",
                    client.acctNum, client.breaker, client.datetime, client.current);
            }
        }
        fclose ( cfPtr );
    }
    return 0;
}
```